# Iframe problems main page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problems with my main page that scroll to iframe content but iframe content is in the middle of the main page and when the user comes to my site the page load on top but automatically scrolls to that iframe content. I need to set the main page not scroll to iframe.

I add to my main page Iframe code

```
<iframe id="test" scrolling="no" src="https://www.example-domain.com/iframe/" width="100%" height="2300px" frameborder="0"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
```

I add to the header

```
<script language="javascript">
function scrollToTop() {
if(document.getElementById("#test") .readyState == "ready")
{
scroll(0,0);
}
}
</script>
```

On my "iframe" page load external data content images styles... 
main.js is on other domain and I can't edit it, but that main.js force scroll my main page to that iframe element

```
<script src="https://example-domain2.com/main.js">
</script>
```

I try code but not work on the main page still automatically scroll to that iframe element.
I can't find a solution to this problem.